# Partial View Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Can I return a view in `PartialViewResult()` like the following?:

```
public PartialViewResult EditAdminProfile_Post(int Id, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            //if (Session["AdminID"] != null)
            //{
            Admin admin = new Admin();
            admin = db.Admins.Single(m => m.ID == Id);
            admin.Name = formCollection[0];
            admin.Gender = formCollection[1];
            admin.Email = formCollection[2];
            admin.ContactNumber = formCollection[3];
            admin.AboutMe = formCollection[4];
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(admin).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return PartialView("AdminProfile");
```

`AdminProfile` is not a partial view.

Comment: Why won't you try that? :)

Comment: i am trying but compile time error @VsevolodGoloviznin

Comment: Then may be you will post the error that you get?

Comment: I guess that physically it is possible,but you'll get some kind of inception (Doubled layout) ;)

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. @VsevolodGoloviznin

Comment: im using this partialview in admin view and return admin view

Comment: debugger stop at this line : @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit Profile", "EditAdminProfile", "Admin", new {Id = Model.ID,@class = "nav nav-tabs" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "profile" })

Comment: You're not passing any model to your view, so it can't find 'Model'

Comment: thanks , @VsevolodGoloviznin

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It's not advised though, since your `_layout` is ignored (which means `css` or `script` files defined in the layout, so your styles and functionality may behave differently as you'd expect). Even though you can make it work, you're looking at **code smell**.

Are you looking to *reuse* `AdminProfile` as **both** a partial and normal view?

- Create a partial view `AdminProfilePartial` with *reusable* content.
- In your `AdminProfile` view, call `AdminProfilePartial` inside it (even if that's all you use)

Then when you return the full view:

```
return View("AdminProfile");
```

Otherwise partial view:

```
return PartialView("AdminProfilePartial");
```

Comment: i have a partial view but when i reuse it, its show another tab and url is also changed

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "its show another tab and url is also changed". Might be good to add your views to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: i have a partial admin view and when i pass it in return view , when it redirect this link is /admin/_adminprofile instead of /admin/AdminProfile

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't pass the model to you partial view, that's why when you call it you get a `Null reference`

Update your code with this line:

```
return PartialView("AdminProfile", admin);
```

PS Instead of using `FormCollection` it's better to use default model binder and accept the `Admin` model in your action method